# NoReverseMatch " " is not a registered namespace

Tags: django

Hello guys I've been struggling to move my project in another location in anaconda so after finally installing everything and setting up the project I am getting some errors that I don't understand. First of all I had my code on a sub-folder inside my app called api there I had my views, serializers, urls. And I included the urls but nothing seemed to happen. I moved all the api files to the app folder and I deleted the api folder. Now I'm getting this error NoReverseMatch at /op_data/objects/    ('api-op-data' is not a registered namespace). Even after deleting this url I keep getting the same error. This is my code:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from djgeojson import views
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
from django.conf.urls.static import static
import MMA
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from MMA import views
from rest_framework_jwt import views
from rest_framework_jwt.views import obtain_jwt_token, refresh_jwt_token, verify_jwt_token

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/auth/token/$', obtain_jwt_token, name='api-auth-token'),
    url(r'^api/', include(('MMA.urls', 'api-op-data'), namespace='api-op-data')),
]
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import OP_Data_RudView, OP_Data_ApiView, UserCreateAPIView, UserLoginAPIView, WoType_ApiView, WoType_RudView, UserObjects_ApiView, UserObjects_RudView


app_name = 'MMA'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^users/register/$', UserCreateAPIView.as_view(), name='register'),
    url(r'^users/login/$', UserLoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
    url(r'^op_data/$', OP_Data_ApiView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate'),
    url(r'^op_data/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', OP_Data_RudView.as_view(), name='post-rud'),
    url(r'^op_data/wo_type/$', WoType_ApiView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate'),
    url(r'^op_data/wo_type/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', WoType_RudView.as_view(), name='post-rud'),
    url(r'^op_data/objects/$', UserObjects_ApiView.as_view(), name='post-listcreate'),
    url(r'^op_data/objects/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', UserObjects_RudView.as_view(), name='post-rud'),  

]
```

error log:

```
NoReverseMatch at /op_data/objects/

'api-op-data' is not a registered namespace

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://---.--.-.---:7000/op_data/objects/
Django Version:     2.0.6
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

'api-op-data' is not a registered namespace

Exception Location:     C:\Users\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\Anaconda3\envs\MMA\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py in reverse, line 86
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\Anaconda3\envs\MMA\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.5
Python Path:    

['C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\Mobile',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator.HR-JUGOR\\Anaconda3\\envs\\MMA\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']

Server time:    Wed, 24 Jul 2019 09:49:27 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

`/op_data/objects/` isn't the configured url for `post-listcreate`, its `api/op_data/objects/`.

In this case the namespace argument seems to be redundant, you already declared the namespace as `'^api/'` before the `include()`, declaring it explicitly as `'api-op-data'` later the same line seems unnecessary based on the code provided, though I would need to see how you were accessing these urls from your views and templates to know for sure.

You also don't need to redeclare your admin url in MMA.urls, and I question your decision to include the `api/auth/token` url in the root url config, it seems like it belongs in MMA.urls with the other urls in the `api` namespace